# Bundling JavaScript modules into a single file

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, modules

I was just going through Modular Design Patterns in JavaScript and I came across bundlers like `browserify` and `webpack`. They solve an interesting problem of combining all dependencies into a monolithic file.

I was interested to see how I can `flatten` out multiple files say `main.js`, `utils.js`, `core.js` written in `commonJSish` format that uses `require` to load other modules which might recursively `require` other modules.

Can someone review this and give me some drawbacks and suggestions? It is `commonJSish` because it doesn't support `export` yet.

Currently, we are using the absolute path as the key. So a consumer has to write the absolute path. One solution would be to allow users to write relative path in the code and the bundler taking care of changing it to absolute paths.

```
// Goal: How to bundle multiple modules into a single file written in 
// commonJSish syntax?

// Premise: I am trying to understand the "browserify" code. So I had to 
// try something myself ...

// This is the core which provides "require".

__cache__ = {}

function require(name){
    if(__cache__[name]){
        console.log("Retreiving from Cache");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Executing " + name + " Module")
        var module = {"exports": {}};
        map[name](module);
        __cache__[name] = module.exports;
    }
    return __cache__[name];
}

map = {}

// This is the module code. A parser can be used to generate this.

// 1. Each of these is a real file in the filesystem.
// 2. The function wrapper doesn't exist in the real file.
// 3. The order doesn't matter.

map['main.js'] = function(module) {
    var utils = require("utils.js");
    var core = require("core.js")
    module.exports.name = "main.js";
    module.exports.dependencies = [utils, core];
};

map['utils.js'] = function(module) {
    module.exports.name = "utils.js"
};

map['core.js'] = function(module) {
    module.exports.name = "core.js"
};

// The entry is just a "require" call.

require("main.js");
```

Comment: #1 issue: `__cache__` and `map` are global.

Comment: https://github.com/browserify/browser-pack/blob/01d39894f7168983f66200e727cdaadf881cd39d/prelude.js seems close. But I need to see it more closely.